# Blank page when using JS print() (other than A4)

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm trying to print my webpage. I have a select tag with options for different sizes (A4, US Letter, etc.). The switch changes the div size to the right size (other elements like nav, footer, etc are set to display:none, the div takes up the whole page).
The problem is that when I set the page to anything other than A4 I can only print blank page (or sometimes 2 blank pages). No content at all, just empty space. I'm trying to "Save as PDF" and "Microsoft Print to PDF" - none of them work. I can't set the page size to a4 and print as US letter, I can't set the page to US letter and print as US letter, etc. Only A4 on A4.

```
                <select class="pdf-select-input page-dimensions-input" id="page-dimensions-input">
                    <optgroup label="Size">
                        <option value="a4">A4</option>
                        <option value="us-letter">US Letter</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="Aspect Ratio">
                        <option value="9-16">9:16</option>
                        <option value="10-16">10:16</option>
                        <option value="2-3">2:3</option>
                        <option value="3-4">3:4</option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
```

```
const pageDimensions:HTMLInputElement | null = document.querySelector(".page-dimensions-input");

function pdfPageDimensions(){

    const elem:HTMLInputElement | null = pageDimensions;

    let inpVal:string = "";

    switch (elem!.value){
        case "a4":
            inpVal = "1/1.41421";
            break;
        case "us-letter":
            inpVal = "1/1.29412";
            break;

        case "9-16":
            inpVal = "1/1.77777";
            break;
        case "10-16":
            inpVal = "1/1.6";
            break;
        case "2-3":
            inpVal = "1/1.5";
            break;
        case "3-4":
            inpVal = "1/1.33333";
            break;
    }

    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${elem?.getAttribute("id")}`, inpVal);

}

pdfPageDimensions();
pageDimensions?.addEventListener("input", pdfPageDimensions);
```

```
@media print{
    
    @page{ 
        margin:0;
        size:letter portrait;
    }

    html, body{
        width:width:100%;
        aspect-ratio:var(--page-dimensions-input);
    }
    
    body > *:not(main),
    nav,
    .sections,
    .close-pdf-btn{
        display:none !important;
    }

    .pdfc-inner-inner{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        aspect-ratio:var(--page-dimensions-input);
    }

}
```

It's a work in progress, so the code is not finished.
I tried to set different @page size (as "letter", in inches, etc.), but nothing works. Is there a way to fix that?